# Spring Integration SFTP fetch daily but process immediately

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I want to filter and fetch files daily and then process that all filtered files immediately.

here is my config;

```
 @Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(downloadFilter));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
    messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    return messageSource;
}
```

and here is my file handler;

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public void handle(File file) {
    log.info("file received . {}", file.getName());
}
```

it fetches the files daily and wait one day to call my handler for each of that fetched files.
I want to consume that fetched files immediately.
is it possible ?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase `maxMessagesPerPoll` on the poller - it defaults to 1.

Or -1 means infinity (while unprocessed files are still present).